# why is $\int_0^x f'/f = \log f(x) - \log f(0)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have $f' = - cf$, $f$ is defined on the space $[0, \infty)$.

So the solution is somehow:

$$f'/f = -c \Rightarrow \int_0^x f'/f = -cx \Rightarrow \log f(x) = \log f(0) - cx \Rightarrow f(x) = e^{-cx}f(0)$$

So why is $\int_0^x f'/f = \log f(x) - \log f(0)$?

Comment: Because if $f'/f = [\ln f]'$ you can apply the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @user296602 Why is $f'/f$ well defined?

Comment: @zhw. It's not guaranteed to be, which is why I hedged a bit in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

The identity is true only for complex valued functions. For real valued functions the identity have the form

$$\int_0^x \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\,\mathrm dt=\ln|f(x)|-\ln|f(0)|$$

The reason is that you can check that the derivative of $\ln |f(x)|$ is $f'(x)/f(x)$ (for real-valued $f$). Then, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, you have the above identity.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\int_0^x \frac{f'(s)}{f(s)} \,ds & = \int \frac{df} f \quad \text{where } df = f'\,ds \\[10pt]
& = \log f.
\end{align}
And as $s$ goes from $0$ to $x$ then $f(s)$ goes from $f(0)$ to $f(s),$ so you get $\log f(s)-\log f(0)$ or $\log\dfrac{f(s)}{f(0)}.$ But the more precise answer is: **the chain rule:**
$$
\frac d {ds} \log f(s) = \big(\log' f(s)\big) \cdot f'(s) = \frac 1 {f(s)} \cdot f'(s).
$$

Comment: What if $f$ is negative?

Comment: @zhw. : Here I assumed $f>0,$ perhaps because it seemed to be assumed in the posted question.

Comment: It's good to make the assumptions clear. I edited my answer to give my point of view on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only assumption I see in the problem is that $f$ is differentiable on $[0,\infty)$ and $f'=cf$ there. From that, you want to derive $f(x) = f(0)e^{cx}.$ You are trying to reach this conclusion with a dubious argument involving $f'/f$ and $\log f$ and such. It's dubious because $f$ could be $0$ somewhere, so that $f'/f$ is problematic. Also, $f<0$ is a possibility, in which case $\log f$ is problematic.

If we add the assumption that $f>0$ on $[0,\infty)$ at the outset, then $\log f$ is fine there, no problem. We then have $(\log f)' = f'/f$ on $[0,\infty)$ by the chain rule and we have the result by the FTC.

Here's a solution that works in all cases, which I think is simpler: Consider the function $e^{cx}f(x).$ Its derivative is $ce^{cx}f(x) + e^{cx} f'(x) \equiv 0.$ Thus $e^{cx}f(x)$ is constant. The value of the constant is $f(0).$ We conclude $f(x) = f(0)e^{-cx}$ for all $x\in [0,\infty).$